# AddChild to a parent's element (from iframe)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, addchild

I would like to add a child to an element like this:

```
myLayout.root.contentItems[ 0 ].addChild( newItemConfig );
```

But from a child (meaning from an iframe):

```
parent.myLayout.root.contentItems[ 0 ].addChild( newItemConfig );
```

I get a function undefined when I call 'addChild'. How can I do that?

BTW I'm trying to do that (https://golden-layout.com/examples/#cdcb9de8e7b305d2ec81b4ae4e392832 , look at JS code) from an iframe

PS My webapp uses angularjs

Comment: Does the iframe have different URL than the parent?

Comment: Isn't array parent.myLayout.root.contentItems empty? If not what does it have (object type)?

Comment: @GrzegorzKaczan no... it has lot of stuff (objects, string, etc...)

Comment: @Rliger Same URL but it seems the problem is because I call from an iframe...

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should use appendChild()?